# Add controls to inherited panel

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have a form `cForm:Form` that has extended client area (you can paint on the frame). Since it kinda breaks the designer (client area 0,0 is on the frame) I made a panel that is always inside the client area `cForm.ClientArea`. When I make a new form `mainForm:cForm` and try to place controls inside the `ClientArea` panel it doesn't let me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have many `Forms` inside a `Form`?

Comment: What happens when you try to add the control? Can you share the class structure here and the code which tries to add controls to the ClientArea?

Answer (score 1):

Designer makes all controls private by default.
Change the control to protected in (form).Desinger.cs or change Modifiers to protected in designer.